# Please add to faq section "What kind of questions can I ask here?"

Tags: feature-request

In the https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#close section in the FAQ, there is a close reason:

> **•general reference** 
>   This question is too basic; it can be definitively
>   and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet
>   reference source designed specifically to find that type of
>   information.

I think similar wording should be added to the https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#questions -> **"But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site."** section.

This came up in the comments on a question I asked today [Meaning and origin of "belt and braces"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42694/meaning-and-origin-of-belt-and-braces)

Comment: This close reason is valid for all SE sites, not only for English SE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But please, don’t ask any questions about these topics. They are out of scope for this site.

The purpose of this section is really to define on-topic questions vs. off-topic questions; you'll note that the other close reasons also aren't mentioned there. General reference questions can be on-topic, but they aren't allowed because they're far too easy to look up.